# Commands to start and stop jekyll site

Tags: jekyll

Which commands do I need to use to start and stop a jekyll site?
I am trying to use

```
jekyll build
```

or

```
jekyll serve
```

but I only get *build* and *serve* folders created instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both commands create a folder containing your website files already processed and ready to make them available using a web server, with the difference that `serve` also starts a server that should be used only for development only at http://localhost:4000.

So you can "start" a Jekyll site with `jekyll build` and then using a server to make those files "available" or you can use `jekyll serve` and then access http://localhost:4000 to browse your website while you develop it.

Comment: When I enter `jekyll serve` a new folder called **serve** is created but it doesn't start the server.

Comment: @alayor but you already have a Jekyll instance? If not, you need to execute: jekyll new mynewsite

Comment: Yes I already have a site. I used to run the server with `jekyll serve`, but now it only creates a folder.

Comment: What folder it creates? if you run it in the root of your project it should generate the files in the `_site` folder.

Comment: It creates a foler called 'serve' in root with these folders inside: **assets** and **posts** and file **index.html**.

Comment: I think I solved my problem. I had to update my ruby version from 1.9 to 2.0 and now I see the server running. Otherwise I was seeing this strange folder creation behavior. Thank you for your help.